# Compare values of 2 column

Tags: excel

I need to compare 2 column A and B.
On column C, must be appear information if values are the same or not.

I'm trying with =EXACT(A1 B1) but without success.

Any help?

Thks all.

```
    A        B       C
1   100      100     OK
2   200      200     OK
3   300      301     ERROR
```

Comment: Try this one: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213367

Comment: Why not just use an if statement `=if(A1=B1,"OK","ERROR")` in c1 then fill down

Comment: `Exact` works on text strings, but should work in this case if you use `=Exact(A1,B1)` (note the comma between `A1` and `B1` which is not present in the example you provided).  It will return `True` or `False`.  Otherwise, @xQbert's suggestion is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use an if statement `=if(A1=B1,"OK","ERROR")` in c1 then fill down